# Why does the property I want to mock need to be virtual?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller, moq

I'm doing some unit testing, and mocking some properties using **Moq**.

Now, this is a **Controller** test (ASP.NET MVC 3). My Controllers derive from an *abstract* controller, called **AbstractController**.

This controller has a dependency on the Http Context (in order to do things like theming, domain-specific logic based on HTTP HOST headers, etc).

This is done via a property called **WebSiteSettings**:

```
public abstract class AbstractController : Controller
{
   public WebSiteSettings WebSiteSettings { get; private set; }

   // other code
}
```

Notice the private set - the ctor sets it up. So, i changed it to used an interface, and that's what i've mocked:

```
public IWebSiteSettings WebSiteSettings { get; private set; }
```

I then created a "FakeWebSiteSettings", which mocks the Http Context in order for it to read the HTTP headers.

The problem is, when i run the test, i get a **NotSupportedException:**

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.WebSiteSettings

Here's the relevant mocking code:

```
var mockWebSiteSettings = new Mock<FakeWebSiteSettings>();
var mockController = new Mock<MyController>(SomeRepository);
mockController.Setup(x => x.WebSiteSettings).Returns(mockWebSiteSettings.Object);

_controller = mockController.Object;

var httpContextBase = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();
httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request.ServerVariables).Returns(new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"HTTP_HOST","localhost.www.mydomain.com"}, 
});
_controller.SetFakeControllerContext(httpContextBase.Object);
```

If i make the `WebsiteSettings` property **virtual** - the test passes.

But i can't understand why i need to do this. I'm not actually *overriding* the property, i'm simply mocking how it is setup.

Am i missing something, or doing this wrong?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Moq and other similar mocking frameworks can only mock interfaces, abstract methods/properties (on abstract classes) or virtual methods/properties on concrete classes.

This is because it generates a proxy that will implement the interface or create a derived class that overrides those overrideable methods in order to intercept calls.

Comment: Only way with Moq. Others such as TypeMock Isolator, Moles can intercept these methods/properties

Answer (score 4):

I've created an interface and wrapper class. e.g.

```
    public interface IWebClient
    {
        string DownloadString(string url);
    }

    public class WebClient : IWebClient
    {
        private readonly System.Net.WebClient _webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

        public string DownloadString(string url)
        {
            return _webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
```

and then in your unit tests just mock out the interface:

```
        var mockWebClient = new Mock<IWebClient>();
```

Obviously you may need to include more properties / methods. But does the trick.

Another useful trick for other mocking problems, such as modifying the current date time (I always use UTC date time):

```
public interface IDateTimeUtcNowProvider
{
    DateTime UtcNow { get; } 
}

public class DateTimeUtcNowProvider : IDateTimeUtcNowProvider
{
    public DateTime UtcNow { get { return DateTime.UtcNow; } }
}
```

e.g. if you have a service that runs every x minutes you can just mock out the IDateTimeProvider and return a time that is later to check the service ran again... or whatever.

Comment: For .NET 5 `ISystemClock`

Answer (score 3):

"So....what i did is the only way?"

No not the only way - you are much better off implementing an interface and mocking that.  Then your actual methods can be virtual or not as you choose.

Comment: I'm interested in this answer but don't understand it!  Giles, could you elaborate, perhaps using RPM1984's original example?

Answer (score 0):

Although, all that was said before is true, it's worth to know that the proxy-mocking  approach (like the one that moq uses)i s not the only one possible.

Check http://www.typemock.com/ for a comprehensive, solution, that allows you to mock both sealed classes, non-virtual methods etc. Pretty powerful.