# Moq requirements? Defeats the purpose?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, automocking

Doesn't being required to virtualize all property accessors you want to mock kind of defeat the purpose of mocking?

I mean, if I have to modify my object and virtualize every single accesor I want to mock, couldn't I just as well inherit my class and mock it myself?

Comment: Except that Moq gives you a much easier way to mock part or all of the object than rolling it yourself.

Comment: or you could augment Moq with i.e. Moles for those kinds of tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very valid but if you think about it,there is no other way to mock a class. If you take an interface, it's just a contract so the mock framework can mock how ever you want it but if you take a class, it already has an implementation for it's members.

So the mock framework, in order to be able to mock the class members, has to inherit from the class and override the member's behavior as requested and for this purpose only virtual members will work.

For eg. if you have (I'm showing methods but the same is true for properties)

```
class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {

    }
    public virtual void  virtualBar()
    {

    }
}
```

then the mock framework probably creates something like this to mock

```
public class MockFoo : Foo
{
    public override void virtualBar()
    {
        // mockery action
    }

    public new void Bar()
    {
        // mockery action
    }
}
```

Now when you have

```
Foo foo = GetMockObject(); // you get an instance of MockFoo
```

now when you call

```
foo.Bar();
```

you don't intend for it to call the actual implementation but since it's a non virtual member, it will call the `Foo`'s `Bar()`

on the other hand, calling

```
foo.VirtualBar();
```

would call `MockFoo`'s `VirtualBar()` as it's a virtual member which would have the behavior injected by the mock framework as requested.

Comment: You'd think somebody might eventually try dropping down a level and emitting IL to hack at regular members to proxy their behaviour through to a mock implementation.

Comment: @John K, There are mocking frameworks that do this. TypeMock Isolator, Telerik JustMock and Moles all do this at the IL level. see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670902/moq-why-does-the-property-i-want-to-mock-need-to-be-virtual/5670936#5670936