# Weird issue with Moq when trying to use Mock<T> for a generic type

Tags: c#, moq

A bit of code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int GetIt();
}

public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    public int GetIt()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

   [Test]
    public void Testit()
    {
        Method<MyImplementation>();
    }

    private void Method<T>()
        where T : class , IMyInterface
    {
        var mock = new Mock<T>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetIt()).Returns(() =>
                                               {
                                                   return 40;
                                               });

        Assert.AreEqual(40, mock.Object.GetIt());
    }
```

Notice that when newing up the Mock I'm using the generic T, however since T is constrained to being a reference type and of type `IMyInterface`, I can set up the methods no problem. For some reason though, it always fails, and calls the actual implementation of `MyImplementation` as opposed to the Mocked one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially mocking a class method and for that the method has to be virtual.

Try

```
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    public virtual int GetIt()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha!! So obvious when you think about it. Good call!

Comment: I'm just curious, why am I not getting an exception. Usually with Moq, when you try to instrument a method that's not virtual, it throws a "NotSupportedException".

Comment: @BFree see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877546/moq-requirements-defeats-the-purpose/5877676#5877676) explains why it does not error but why it does not do what you expect it to do.