# Invalid setup on a non virtual member using MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

I'm moqing an interface which has:

`Dictionary<string, object> InstanceVariables { get; set; }`

I've created a new mock of the interface and trying to set it up so it returns just a random string like so:

`_mockContext.SetupGet(m => m.InstanceVariables[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(@"c:\users\randomplace");`

But I seem to get an error:

`{"Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.InstanceVariables[It.IsAny<String>()]"}`

What does this mean exactly? I am mocking the interface so shouldn't this not be a problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to mock a `Dictionary` if you can create a dictionary will all required fields?

Comment: Because I want to change what comes out of InstanceVariables when I execute the method that I've passed in my mockContext object into

Comment: Your property is a `Dictionary`, not an `IDictionary`. Therefore, to make it compile you must be mocking the concrete implementation, *not* the interface as you state (although I can't know that for sure, as you didn't post that code). Therefore, the error is correct - you can't override a non-virtual member (and the dictionary indexer is not virtual). However, @Valentin's question still stands - why not just create a dictionary with the values set as you desire for your unit test - a dictionary is a dumb data-store - there is no functionality there to mock!

Answer (score 7):

There's a number of reasons I'd advise against it. Firstly, as mentioned in the comments there's no reason why a real dictionary wouldn't work here. [We shouldn't mock types that what we don't own](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) and [only mock types we do own](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/12/13/tdd-only-mock-types-you-own/). 
The line `_mockContext.SetupGet(m => m.InstanceVariables[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(@"c:\users\randomplace");` is trying to mock the `Get` on `Dictionary<T, T>` which as @RB notes isn't `virtual`, hence your error. You may be mocking *your* interface, but the set up there is on the *.NET* dictionary.

Secondly, IMO, `It.IsAny<string>()` leads to quite weak tests, because it will respond to, well, any string. Structuring something like:

```
const string MyKey = "someKey";

var dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add(MyKey, @"c:\users\randomplace");
_mockContext.Setup(m => m.InstanceVariables).Returns(dictionary);

var sut = new SomeObject(_mockContext.Object());
var result = sut.Act(MyKey);

// Verify
```

will be stronger as the dictionary can only respond with the path if the correct key is given to / or generated by your System Under Test (sut).

---

That said, if you absolutely must mock a dictionary, for reasons that aren't apparent on the question... then the property on your interface needs to be the interface for the dictionary, `IDictionary`, not the concrete class:

```
IDictionary<string, object> InstanceVariables { get; set; }
```

Then you can create the dictionary mock via:

```
var dictionary = new Mock<IDictionary<string, object>>();
dictionary.SetupGet(d => d[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(@"c:\users\randomplace");
```

Then on the context mock:

```
_mockContext.SetupGet(d => d.InstanceVariables).Returns(dictionary.Object);
```

---

**Why does it need to be Virtual?**

> Moq and other similar mocking frameworks can only mock interfaces,
>   abstract methods/properties (on abstract classes) or virtual
>   methods/properties on concrete classes.
>
> This is because it generates a proxy that will implement the interface
>   or create a derived class that overrides those overrideable methods in
>   order to intercept calls. 
>   
> <sub>[Credit to @aqwert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670902/why-does-the-property-i-want-to-mock-need-to-be-virtual)</sub>

Comment: Good answer. To see that the indexer of the concrete class `Dictionary<,>` is indeed non-virtual, see [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx). To see that the interface `IDictionary<,>` includes the member (the indexer), see [its page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyxt2e2h.aspx). I absolutely agree that it is probably best to create a standard populated `Dictionary<,>` in the test, and return that from the mock. However, in the second approach, you do not have to setup `It.IsAny<string>()`. You can setup only `d => d["someKey"]` if you want.